# File editing Geoserver Rest Api SpringBoot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, rest, put, geoserver

Can You help me edit the file?
First off how should it work. The {stylere} file is a path variable of course.
When I will **enter http://localhost:8055/edit-style/{stylere} I get the form on the page with save button**. In this form I have a **textarea with the text of {stylere} file**. And now listen to me carefully. **The js is connected to another getMapping which is http://localhost:8055/{stylere}**. This mapping **display on page the content of file with name {stylere}.sld**. **The files come from http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles**. On this link you have list of all styles from geoserver, but I display only one in time so I get the **content of the file by [http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles/{stylere}.sld](http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles/%7Bstylere%7D.sld)**.

So generally I want to edit style from file that I can find on [http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles/{stylere}.sld](http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles/%7Bstylere%7D.sld) by my form on http://localhost:8055/edit-style/{stylere} and save the changes by the button in js with **PUT method**. That`s all. I hope You understand

Here is Java code

```
package exp.tries;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

@RestController
public class StyleController {

private final WebClient webClient;

public StyleController(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, createBasicAuthHeader())
            .build();
}

private String createBasicAuthHeader() {
    String auth = "geoserver:geoserver";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{style}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<String> getDefaultPointStyle(@PathVariable String style) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/" + style + ".sld")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

@GetMapping("/edit-style/{stylere}")
public ClassPathResource getEditStylePage(@PathVariable String stylere) {
    return new ClassPathResource("/templates/edit_style.html");
}
}
```

And Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edycja pliku SLD</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/
5.62.0/codemirror.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Edycja pliku SLD dla stylu</h1>
<form id="sldForm">
<textarea id="sldContent" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="saveChanges()">Zapisz</button>
</form>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.62.0/code
mirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/
5.62.0/mode/xml/xm l.min.js"></script>

<script>
const urlString = window.location.href;
const urlParts = urlString.split('/');
const lastWord = "/" + urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]

const sldContentTextarea = document.getElementById('sldContent');
const codeMirrorInstance = 
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea(sldContentTextarea, {
    mode: 'xml',
    lineNumbers: true,
    theme: 'default',
});

function fetchAndSetContent() {
    fetch(lastWord)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(content => {
            codeMirrorInstance.setValue(content);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Wystąpił błąd podczas pobierania 
            zawartości pliku SLD', error);
        });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fetchAndSetContent);

function saveChanges() {
    const newContent = codeMirrorInstance.getValue();
    fetch(lastWord, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        body: newContent
    })
    .then(() => {
        alert('Zapisano zmiany!');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert('Wystąpił błąd podczas zapisywania zmian.');
        console.error(error);
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>



**@PutMapping(value = "/{style}", consumes = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> updateStyle(@PathVariable String 
style, @RequestBody String newContent) {
    return webClient.put()
            .uri("/" +  style + ".sld", style)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(newContent))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String.class)
            .map(response -> {
                System.out.println("Received response status code: " 
+ response.getStatusCodeValue());
                if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    return ResponseEntity.ok("Zawartość pliku SLD 
została zaktualizowana.");
                } else {
                    return 
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Błąd 
podczas aktualizacji zawartości pliku SLD.");
                }
            })
            
 .onErrorReturn(ResponseEntity.status
  (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error"));
 }
 }));
 }**
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do? and what exactly is not working - including error messages, and relevant log file extracts. I would break your problem into 2 parts, what do you need for the REST and what the spring boot might need to do to send that

Comment: Okay, so exactly. I have the mapping with path of edit-style/{stylere} and when I will enter this url I have a form from html/js that contains a xml style of name {stylere} (this is path variable of course). My goal is to use the button that is on the site to save the edits from form AND what is the most important save the changes to the file from I get this xml. And this file is on http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles//{stylere}. When u will enter http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles//{stylere} u will see the text that is a link to download the file with name {stylere}.sld

Comment: So exactly the {stylere}.sld is the file that I want to edit via form and save it with those changes. I hope You understand what I mean.

Comment: What do You think @IanTurton?

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to do to the style, please post the actual XML you send to GeoServer and explain what your problem is. Please use the [edit] button

Comment: I did it. Hope it`s okay now. And again by a shortcut what I want to do to the style. I want to edit it via form. There is no problem with XML. But the problem is that I don`t know how to edit and save the changes from form to change the actual file content {stylere].sld

Comment: So this a Spring Boot question not a GeoServer REST question, in that case I can't really help. Maybe looking at the code for the GeoServer Style editor will help?

Comment: @IanTurton unlucky. Okay thank you then for asnwers. I will try some things or maybe some other people will know the answer.

Comment: I think you still need to clarify what your problem is? what is not working?

Comment: my PUT method do not work cause i made a simple PUT to file and even this do not work.

@PutMapping(value = "/{sty}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> update(@PathVariable String sty,
@RequestBody String cont) {
return webClient.put()
.uri("/" +  sty+ ".sld", sty)
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(cont))
.retrieve()
.toEntity(String.class)
.map(response -> {
if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) 
return ResponseEntity.ok("Zawartość pliku SLD została zaktualizowana.");
else  return "";
 }));
}

Comment: I gave u a little more clear PUT on the low part of code in HTML section

Comment: @IanTurton Do You maybe know how to add new style into rest api geoserver with spring boot? Cause I think that I do not have acces to it

Comment: Step 1: - craft a correct XML document and PUT it to the rest endpoint using `curl` or `postman` or what ever https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/rest/api/styles.html#styles-s-format - if this works proceed to use spring (for whatever reason) and repeat creating that XML to PUT

Comment: But will it work if even creating empty style does not work from spring boot in my situation

Comment: As I said you have two distinct problems - 1) update a style using REST, 2) make spring boot generate the required style changes. I can only help with 1 and to do that I need to see the XML and the URL of the PUT request

Comment: Xml: 
<StyledLayerDescriptor version=\"1.0.0\">
<NamedLayer><Name>" + styleName + "</Name></NamedLayer></StyledLayerDescriptor>


URL what do you mean the endpoint? I Have the Put method on  http://localhost:8056/create/poste

Comment: OK that will associate the style with a layer - where are you sending the SLD to

Comment: I do PUT method with sld to  http://10.56.56.66:8080/geoserver/rest/styles and with added style it is in http://10.56.56.66:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/style.sld

Comment: OK, and what doesn't work?

Comment: No unlucky. Like my main thing is to edit this file from 10.56.56.66:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/style.sld to the changes on my form in html. But does not work. I even tried some simple things with PUT or POST in postman but it does not give anything. But serveral times i had error 500. I think that this is something behind geoserver. I checked logs and there are some problem with memory as i could see and some with threads too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254652/discussion-between-ian-turton-and-piterek237).

Comment: @IanTurton could You please come to the chat again? I would appreciate it. I have the last question this time stricte about geoserver